# Convert Nested list into single data frame or tibble

Tags: r, nested-lists, purrr

I have a very large nested list that I'd like to make to a flat data frame. I created a dput of the first two elements of the list to quickly copy/paste (sorry it's got a lot of nonesense I can clean after creating the df) I tried following similar SO questions about converting lists to df but none seem to be compatible with mine for some reason.

Thank you!

Here is the dput of the first two elements - the full list has thousands:

```
list(structure(list(first = structure(list(text = c("\n\tMenghe a'Nyam\n\t\n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n          
Position:\n  \n  Forward\n\n\n\n  6-5, 215lb (196cm, 97kg) \n  \n\n  \n\n  \n  \n  \n\n  School:     
Canisius\n\n\n\n\n\n  More player info\n\n\n\n\n\n"  , 
"\n\tMenghe a'Nyam\n\t\n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n  Position:\n  \n  Forward\n\n\n\n  6-5, 215lb 
(196cm, 97kg) \n  \n\n  \n\n  \n  \n  \n\n  School: Canisius\n\n\n\n\n\n  More player 
info\n\n\n\n\n\n"  , 
"\n\tMenghe a'Nyam\n\t\n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n  Position:\n  \n  Forward\n\n\n\n  6-5, 215lb 
(196cm, 97kg) \n  \n\n  \n\n  \n  \n  \n\n  School: Canisius\n\n\n\n\n\n  More player 
info\n\n\n\n\n\n"  
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)), second = structure(list(Season = c("2006-07", "2007-08", 
"Career"), name = c("menghe-anyam", "menghe-anyam", "menghe-anyam"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(
first = structure(list(text = c("\n\tJordan Aaberg\n\t\n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n  Position:\n  \n  
Forward\n\n\n\n  6-9, 225lb (206cm, 102kg) \n  \n\n  Hometown: Rothsay, MN\n\n\n\n  \n\n  High 
School: Rothsay\n\n\n\n  \n  \n  \n\n  School: North Dakota State\n\n\n\n\n\n  More player 
info\n\n\n\n\n\n"  , 
"\n\tJordan Aaberg\n\t\n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n  Position:\n  \n  Forward\n\n\n\n  6-9, 225lb 
(206cm, 102kg) \n  \n\n  Hometown: Rothsay, MN\n\n\n\n  \n\n  High School: Rothsay\n\n\n\n  \n  \n  
\n\n  School: North Dakota State\n\n\n\n\n\n  More player info\n\n\n\n\n\n"  , 
"\n\tJordan Aaberg\n\t\n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n  Position:\n  \n  Forward\n\n\n\n  6-9, 225lb 
(206cm, 102kg) \n  \n\n  Hometown: Rothsay, MN\n\n\n\n  \n\n  High School: Rothsay\n\n\n\n  \n  \n  
\n\n  School: North Dakota State\n\n\n\n\n\n  More player info\n\n\n\n\n\n"  , 
"\n\tJordan Aaberg\n\t\n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n  Position:\n  \n  Forward\n\n\n\n  6-9, 225lb 
(206cm, 102kg) \n  \n\n  Hometown: Rothsay, MN\n\n\n\n  \n\n  High School: Rothsay\n\n\n\n  \n  \n  
\n\n  School: North Dakota State\n\n\n\n\n\n  More player info\n\n\n\n\n\n"  , 
"\n\tJordan Aaberg\n\t\n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n\n  \n  Position:\n  \n  Forward\n\n\n\n  6-9, 225lb 
(206cm, 102kg) \n  \n\n  Hometown: Rothsay, MN\n\n\n\n  \n\n  High School: Rothsay\n\n\n\n  \n  \n  
\n\n  School: North Dakota State\n\n\n\n\n\n  More player info\n\n\n\n\n\n"  
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)), second = structure(list(Season = c("2009-10", "2011-12", 
"2012-13", "2013-14", "Career"), name = c("jordan-aaberg", 
"jordan-aaberg", "jordan-aaberg", "jordan-aaberg", "jordan-aaberg"
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the data in one dataframe you can use :

```
newdata <- do.call(rbind, lapply(data, function(x) do.call(cbind, x)))
```

Or using `purrr` :

```
newdata <- purrr::map_df(data, ~do.call(cbind, .x))
```

Comment: elegant solution! Thank you! It works perfectly. Can you help explain to me the difference between map_df and map_dfr? Also, do.call, what exactly is that function doing?

Comment: Most of the times they both work exactly the same so in this case, you can also use `map_dfr`. `do.call` applies a function (`cbind` in this case) on a list of dataframes and combines them into one dataframe.

Comment: Thank you. I'll do some research on these calls to add it to my learning. @RonakShah I appreciate you so much!

Answer (score 0):

We can just do `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% bind_rows
```